# System crashes when converting many images in Imagemagick with one command

Tags: 12.04, performance, image-processing, convert, imagemagick

After upgrading to precise, I have several times had my system freeze completely when I try to convert to many (100, 200) jpegs or pngs to pdf. Or, sometimes, that does not happen, but I get an unreadable pdf.

With a small number of images all seems ok.

Is there a limit to the number of files that can be converted in Imagemagick with one command like

```
convert *.jpg new.pdf
```

or is something else the matter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to define `pdf` page setting.

Type into terminal

```
convert -page A4 *.jpg xxx.pdf
```

Where `xxx` is the file name. There is no limitation of image quantity. But lots of image need more time to generate a `pdf` file.

Comment: Yes. I have just used that command on the very images that would not convert with the simpler command (and had blocked my system).And it worked perfectly. Thanks.